# Is it possible to test if command is triggered by SharePoint UI or Powershell

Tags: custom-timer-job

I have a custom job definition for which I have created a Description override. I want it to have correct formatting when called via Central administration UI and when seen using Powershell. Does SharePoint/C# have a way to do this?

Proper UI Override

```
 public override string Description(){
        get{   return "content with <br/> line break"; }
 }
```

Proper PS Override

```
 public override string Description(){
       get{   return "content with \n\r line break"; }
 }
```

Looking for something along the lines of

```
 public override string Description(){
       get{   
             string str ="content with<br/> line beak";
             If(sender == system.console)
                      str= "content with \n\r line break"; 
            return str;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the Status of "HttpConext" ? Like this:

```
    if(HttpContext.Current!=null){

       //......
     }
```

it's may work,but i'm not really sure....

Regards, [Raymond](http://www.sharepointadd-ons.com)